# How to maintain 100% magnification using imshow( ) in a number of iterations?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to display a set of images in the same figure window, at 100% magnification. At the same time, I would like to apply an annotation object onto each image.

Assuming that my input image does not exceed the screen size, this is what I have done :

```
imagedata = imread('cameraman.tif');

hFig = figure;
hAnnot = [];

for n = 1 : 10 % repeat ten times

    % show and annotate image
    imshow(imagedata, 'InitialMagnification', 100, 'border', 'tight');
    if(isempty(hAnnot) || ~ishandle(hAnnot))
        hAnnot = annotation('arrow', 'color', 'b');
    end


    set(gca, 'units', 'pixels');
    gcapos = get(gca, 'Position');


    % add label to display no of loop
    text(10, 10, [' Loop : ', num2str(n)], 'Color', 'c')

    pause(1);   % pause one second to view

    if(ishandle(hAnnot))
        % remove hAnnot to prevent reappearance in next loop
        delete(hAnnot);

        % check if annotation object is successfully removed
        if(~ishandle(hAnnot))
            hAnnot = [];
        else
            sprintf('hAnnot is not cleared in loop #%d', n);
        end

    end

end
```

The results shows that only the first `imshow()` -ed image is shown at 100% magnification. and gca's position returned at [ 1     1   256   256 ], which is what I wanted.

The subsequent images (from loop 2 to 10) were zoom-ed out, and the position is now returned at  [34.2800   29.1600  198.4000  208.6400].

Could anyone help to explain why does it behave in such a way?

I also looked into hFig's properties in every loop to find out if there is any changes. The only difference I have observed is the value of 'NextPlot' - in which 1st loop is 'replacechildren', while it is 'add' in the subsequent loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it's happening, but a quick fix would be to get the position in the first iteration and set it in the others:

```
if (n==1)
    gcapos=get(gca,'position');
else
    set(gca,'position',gcapos);
end
```

Comment: Thanks Hugh for your help! I tried your method and the axis position is fixed. :)

If possible I would like to understand why does it behave this way - the problem occurs only if an annotation object is added onto the same figure..